# ld: library not found for -lpj-arm-apple-darwin9 error

Tags: xcode, arm

I'm learning Xcode

but The errors in pjsip com files happened.

```
Ld build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Siphon.app/Siphon normal i386
cd /Users/mac/siphon/Siphon2
setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -arch i386 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.2.sdk -L/Users/mac/siphon/Siphon2/build/Debug-iphonesimulator -L/Users/mac/siphon/Siphon2/../../pjproject_sim/pjlib/lib -L/Users/mac/siphon/Siphon2/../../pjproject_sim/pjsip/lib -L/Users/mac/siphon/Siphon2/../../pjproject_sim/pjmedia/lib -L/Users/mac/siphon/Siphon2/../../pjproject_sim/pjlib-util/lib -L/Users/mac/siphon/Siphon2/../../pjproject_sim/pjnath/lib -L/Users/mac/siphon/Siphon2/../../pjproject_sim/third_party/lib -F/Users/mac/siphon/Siphon2/build/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/mac/siphon/Siphon2/build/Siphon.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Siphon.build/Objects-normal/i386/Siphon.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -framework Foundation -framework UIKit -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -framework SystemConfiguration -framework UIKit -framework AddressBookUI -framework AddressBook -framework Foundation -framework AudioToolbox -lpj-arm-apple-darwin9 -lpjlib-util-arm-apple-darwin9 -lpjnath-arm-apple-darwin9 -lpjmedia-arm-apple-darwin9 -lpjsip-arm-apple-darwin9 -lpjsip-simple-arm-apple-darwin9 -lpjsip-ua-arm-apple-darwin9 -lpjsua-arm-apple-darwin9 -framework CoreGraphics -lsqlite3.0 -lpjmedia-codec-arm-apple-darwin9 -lgsmcodec-arm-apple-darwin9 -framework CFNetwork -lpjmedia-audiodev-arm-apple-darwin9 -lresample-arm-apple-darwin9 -lg7221codec-arm-apple-darwin9 -lg729a -framework IOKit -o /Users/mac/siphon/Siphon2/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Siphon.app/Siphon

ld: library not found for -lpj-arm-apple-darwin9
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1
```